# abrir dos ventanas con un formulario PHP

Tags: html, botón, onclick

como puedo hacer que un boton de un formulario me direccione a dos ventanas diferentes....una para ir a la ventana principal del sistema y otra para abrir el form en otra ventana en PHP

Comment: Puedes agregar el código que has intentado?

Comment: <form target="_blank" action="formulario.php" method="POST"><input type="submit" value="EL BOTON" name="1" class="btn btn-warning btn-block animated infinite pulse center-block">

Comment: estoy enviando con _blank a una ventana ...pero al mismo tiempo quiero que esa ventana del formulario se vaya a la ventana pricipal del sistema

Comment: tendrias que usar javascript para hacer eso

Comment: un ejemplo porfavor

Comment: te deje un ejemplo abajo en la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Lo que se me ocurre es utilizar javascript. Es una manera muy simple de hacerlo, te dejo un ejemplo. Recuerda cambiar las url por las que tu desees y tambien tener habilitadas las ventanas emergentes.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ventanas() {
    window.open("https://www.facebook.com/");
    window.open("https://www.google.com.ar/");
}
</script>
</head>
 
<body>
<form>
<input type=button value="Abrir" onclick="ventanas()">
</form>
</body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Te pido por favor que si te sirvió la respuesta la marques como la que utilizaste. Muchas gracias.